# Cannot put two DropDownButtons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dropdownbutton

I'm trying to put two DropdownButtons in the same app, but it doesn't seem to work 'cause `value2` doesn't seem to change. Could you help me? Thanks in advance!

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(FirestoreApp());
}

class FirestoreApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirestoreApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirestoreAppState createState() => _FirestoreAppState();
}

class _FirestoreAppState extends State<FirestoreApp> {
  String? value;
  String? value2;

  String prof = '';
  String points = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference collection =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Prof');

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 200,
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12,100, 12, 12),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 4)
                ),
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: value,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  items: <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[
                    DropdownMenuItem(value: null, child: Text('Seleziona'), ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(value: '1', child: Text('1'), ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(value: '2', child: Text('2'), ),    
                  ],
                  onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                    this.value = value;
                    prof = value!;
                  }),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: 1000,
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12,100, 12, 12),
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 4)
                ),
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  value: value2,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  items: <DropdownMenuItem<String>>[
                    DropdownMenuItem(value: null, child: Text('a'), ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(value: '20', child: Text('b'), ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(value: '15', child: Text('c'), ),
                    DropdownMenuItem(value: '30', child: Text('d'), ),
                  ],
                  onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
                    this.value = value2;
                    points = value2!;
                  }),
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
        ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.save),
        onPressed: () {
          if (prof != null && points != null) {
            collection.doc('EtaApkQZConQUXzAS4JH').update({'$prof': FieldValue.increment(int.parse(points))});
          }
          setState(() {
            prof = '';
            points = '';
          });
        })
      )
    );
  }

}
```

P.S. Actually, there are more DropdownMenuItems, but I removed them to make the code more readable

Answer (score 0):

On your second `DropDownButton` you are settting the variable `value` to `value2`. You switched those variables and it is the reason why `value2` never gets an update. To fix it set `value2` to `value`.

```
onChanged: (value) => setState(() {
  // this.value = value2;
  value2 = value;
  points = value2!;
}),
```